# How to find references to a class that's referenced indirectly via exported jar in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

I have two Eclipse projects, `Project_A` and `Project_B`. `Project_B` is compiled and exported as a `.jar` file that's used by `Project_A`.

Is there a way to select a class in `Project_B` and find all references to it in *both* `Project_A` and `Project_B`?

Normally I'd use `"Find all References" (Ctrl + Shift + G)` for this, but it doesn't consider a reference via exported jar to be a "reference".

I know I can use a file search, but I'm hoping there's something more clever I can do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a plug-in project, all of its dependencies have to be from *other* *plug-ins* and declared using its `MANIFEST.MF` file. Being packaged in a `.jar` has nothing to do with it. At runtime, the stated dependencies are wired by Equinox. At development time, PDE uses your MANIFEST.MF to set up the project's `Java Build Path` allowing you to use the normal `Java Search` capabilities. In general, don't modify plug-in projects' `Java Build Paths` yourself.

Comment: In the circumstance that a plugin project requires a jar I don't own (for the sake of example, let's say gson.jar) what's the best practice I should use? Is there a way to package or declare gson.jar as a plugin?

Comment: You either have to add a MANIFEST.MF to it, or create a plug-in that has that jar as part of its runtime and Exports all of the jar's Packages (from the Plug-in Manifest Editor's Runtime tab).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. instead of compile and export project b as a jar, you just put it together with project a.
2. right click on project a, select properties--Java Build Path, select "Projects" tab and then add project b to it

Then try do Ctrl + Shift + G

Don't blame me if it doesn't work  :)

Comment: Normally that's what I would do. Unfortunately I can't do that in this situation. Project_A is an Eclipse plugin project, and that seems to require that all of its dependencies are included via .jar files.